# chartjs - how do I add border radius on bottom corners

Tags: css, chart.js

[image]

Basically the top picture is how I want it to look like and the bottom picture is how it looks now. 
I'm using chart.js but I couldn't find any settings for the bottom border radius. 
Help is much appreciated.

Here's a picture update as response to the comment below:

[image]

My code:

```
 
   var options= {
     responsive: true,
     maintainAspectRatio: true,
     animation: {
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad', duration: 520
    }
    ,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [ {
            gridLines: {
                display: false, drawBorder: false
            }
            ,
            ticks: {
                display: false
            }
        }
        ],
        yAxes: [ {
            gridLines: {
                display: false, drawBorder: false
            }
            ,
            ticks: {
                display: false
            }
        }
        ]
    }
    ,
    elements: {
        labels: {
            display: false
        }
    }
    ,
    legend: {
        display: false,
        labels: {
            display: false
        }
    }
    ,
    point: {
        display: false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) on the `canvas` element to achieve this:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["", "", "", "", ""],
    datasets: [{
      data: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok, so I tried adding the border and I've noticed that left and bottom have padding somewhere in the canvas that I'm unable to hide. I've added my code above.

Comment: @CsgoTalksCom You need to set `xAxes: [{ display: false }]` and `yAxes: [{ display: false }]`, as in my example, instead of disabling the parts individually. Otherwise Chart.js still accounts for the axes in the positioning.